# Tidy Rolling Window

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to see if someone can provide a tidy version of the following problem (ideally in a pipe or something that does not require a loop). I am trying to take a date column, and from it extract a nested list, with each containing 24 dates (sequential).

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(lubridate) 
df <-read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nicktz/ExDat/master/extdata/findata.csv") %>% gather(Stock, Price, -Date) %>% 
filter(Date <= ymd(20070501)) %>% mutate(Ret = Price / lag(Price) - 1)

DateCol <- df %>% pull(Date) %>% unique

# Roll Window 
Roll_Window <- list()  
Min_Window <- 24

for( i in Min_Window:length(DateCol)){

  Roll_Window[c(i-Min_Window)+1] <-
    list(DateCol[c(i-Min_Window+1):i]) 
}
```

Comment: There is no Stock column in df.  Please fix the code. rollapply can handle any function that returns a fixed length vector so I see no valid reason for the last sentence unless you can demonstrate otherwise.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - apologies, I've simplified the question now. As mentioned, I am not interested in rollapply - I require the nested list format as, among other reasons, downstream use does conditional formatting of date column. I should've known that my efforts at a simple example of why someone would be interested in this format will confuse matters.

Comment: `library(zoo); r <- rollapply(DateCol, 24, c); L <- lapply(1:nrow(r), function(i) DateCol[r[i, ]]); identical(L, Roll_Window)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks - I adjusted your code to now work: library(zoo); r <- as.Date(rollapply(DateCol, 24, c) ) ; L <- lapply(1:nrow(r), function(i) r[i, ]) ;identical(L, Roll_Window). But this still feels a bit hacky (untidy).